# Does the Dual-boot in secure mode works the other way?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, uefi, secure-boot

Its a common error that users can't boot into Windows through Grub while using Secure-boot. Some "image not found" error comes up. Disabing secure-boot works though.
That is when when we install ubuntu after Windows.

Does this happen even if we install Windows later than Ubuntu & use Windows loader to get into Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say that it definitely occurs in that case, but I don't see why it wouldn't. The problem is basically a GRUB limitation. As such, the order of OS installation is unlikely to make any difference, unless that results in some subtle change to the GRUB configuration that works around the problem. As I know of no such simple workaround, it seems unlikely that order of installation would make any difference even if that changed the GRUB configuration. Furthermore, installing Windows after Ubuntu will cause GRUB to become the secondary boot loader, which means you'll have no OS boot selection menu when you start -- you'll just boot straight to Windows. This is easily corrected if you know how, but it's an extra step.

FWIW, the bug you refer to is [reported here.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1091464) If you're affected by the bug and haven't already done so, please click the "Does this bug affect you" link and confirm that you're affected. This will raise the "heat" on the bug and make it more likely that it will be fixed.

Also, if you're affected by the bug, a number of workarounds are described in the comments. Aside from disabling Secure Boot, these include using the firmware's own boot manager (comment #9) and using my [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) (comment #11; note that installation is easier today than it was two years ago, when I posted that comment -- simply installing the rEFInd PPA or Debian package should do almost everything automatically, provided rEFInd detects a valid copy of Shim).